# Why can't I log in as the seeded user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a new ASP.NET MVC project, using individual accounts stored in the database for authentication. Here's my class that will seed the database with sample data every time I test:

```
public class DevelopmentInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);

        var applicationUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        var sampleUserOne = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "SampleUser", Email = "sample@example.com" };
        var result = applicationUserManager.Create(sampleUserOne, "aaaaaa");

        if (!result.Succeeded) 
            throw new Exception();

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The `Login` action is as it is in the template:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The description of problem is very simple: **Trying to log in using the seeded user's credentials fails.**

Specifically, the `FindAsync` method returns `null`, even though the user is present in the database - `FindByEmailAsync` does find the seeded user.

However, creating a new account works and allows me to log in.

**Why can't I log in as the seeded user, even though I can register a new account and log in using that?**

I'm suspecting it has to do with how the passwords are hashed, but I don't know how to confirm this.

Am I seeding the account wrong? Should I not be creating a separate `ApplicationUserManager` in the `Seed` method? If not, how should I get one in order to call `Create`? I'm trying to understand how the new system works, before ending up locked out of my account or the users end up locked out of theirs in a deployed application.

Comment: Isn't the Create() method async?  If so, the applicationUserManager.Create(...) call would need to be awaited.

Comment: No, but `CreateAsync` is. However, it doesn't really make a difference. The user is seeded successfully, it's the provided password that's always wrong when attempting to log in.

Comment: And to verify the silly things.... 1) the `username` and `password` passed into the `Login` action are correct, and 2) are you using `email` when you should be using `username`?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Ummm... Yes, you're right. The sample code misled me: `Find` and `FindAsync` expect the username, not the email. Care to make this an answer?

Comment: Glad to help.  Have added an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
```

is expecting the userName to be passed in, not the email address.

This simple change should take care of things:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the definition of PasswordSignInAsync, it requires the username string and not the email. Maybe the reason why the UI for login ask for email is because of the autogenerated code where the email would be equal to username inside the controller.