# Why can't I log in with the newly seeded power user (Asp.Net Core Identity)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have an Asp.Net Core 3.1 web app with Identity. I use this code to seed a power user to the database:

```
var poweruser = new ApplicationUser
{
    UserName = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserName"],
    Email = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserEmail"],
    FirstName = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserFirstName"],
    LastName = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserLastName"],
    PhoneNumber = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserPhoneNumber"]
};

string userPassword = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserPassword"];
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserEmail"]);

if (user == null)
{
    var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, userPassword);
    if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
    {
        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "SiteAdmin");
    }
}
```

In `appsettings.json`, the section "AppSettings" looks like this:

```
"AppSettings": {
  "UserName": "ab@cd.ef",
  "UserEmail": "ab@cd.ef",
  "UserFirstName": "Admin",
  "UserLastName": "Admin",
  "UserPhoneNumber":  "12345678",
  "UserPassword": "pa5sw&Rd"
}
```

The user is created in the database:

[image]

But when I try to log in, I get a failed login attempt. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207011/seeding-database-with-admin-user-but-he-cant-log-in) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415944/why-cant-i-log-in-as-the-seeded-user) similar post, but in those cases, the username and email address were not identical. In my case, they are (ab@cd.ef). I copy-pasted the password from appsettings.json to make sure I wasn't mistyping.

**Update**

This is the method receiving the login form (Login.cshtml.cs):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Where is your login implementation? Please include your login implementation on the question

Comment: Identity always return feedback associated to the operations that the user attempts to get done. So On your PasswordSignInAsync() that method returns login result object with errors on it, so you must  try to find out what those errors are.

Comment: Check the logs to see what failed during login. Also, can you share your identity configuration? It’s possible for example that you require confirmed accounts, and you don’t confirm your admin account.

Comment: @MosiaThabo I have added the login-implementation to my question.I'l look more into debugging the result object tomorrow.

Comment: You are doing everything right as far as your implementation is concerned. Let me see what I can find out. I also hope that cookies are enabled in your Browser? Because Identity Framework works with Cookies. But again this wouldn't be the case because you are basically prohibited access, let alone session creation.

Comment: @MosiaThabo `PhoneNumberConfirmed` was the culprit. It was required to be set to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you hate it when the solution to a difficult problem turns out to be simple?

In this case, all it took was to set `PhoneNumberConfirmed` to `true`, and I was able to log in...